# Combine code with info from databound item in ASP.NET markup code blocks

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, markup

Man, I never really learnt all the embedded code blocks and stuff you can use in ASP.NET. What I'm trying to do is the following:

- I have a repeater
- It renders a table
- In each row, I need to add a `data-bind` attribute (yes, for Knockout) containing some text and the rowindex.

More specifically, I want to render:

```
<table>
    <tr data-bind="with:myItems()[0]">
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="with:myItems()[1]">
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="with:myItems()[2]">
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried:

```
data-bind="<%# String.Format("myItems()[{0}]", Container.ItemIndex) %>"
```

But that doesn't work (`data-bind="<%# Container.ItemIndex %>` will however. So I'm trying to combine code with information from the databound item.

I know there is a `foreach` binding in Knockout, but I can't use it because:

- I want/need my HTML to be constructed server-side initially
- There's other, specific javascript that needs the HTML to exist already so I can't let Knockout populate the table
- I'm using an ASP.NET Repeater, which doesn't mix well with Knockout's templates.

I also know, I could just do this in code-behind (with `<tr runat="server" ... >`) but I'm trying to put all my layout and javascript in markup and js files, not in C# code.

So, can I, in some way, add code in my markup to combine text I choose, with info from the current databound item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bummer, apparently, the answer is dead simple, and it didn't work the first time because of another mistake I made:

```
<tr data-bind="with: myItems()[<%# Container.ItemIndex %>]">
```

I put more info on [my Blog](http://petermorlion.blogspot.be/2013/05/knockoutjs-foreach-binding-and-old.html) and a working example on [GitHub](https://github.com/petermorlion/AspNetRepeaterAndKnockout).